# Pass additional data back from Wearable to Activity

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I need to pass additional data when showing a notification on a wearable from a smartphone app which will then be passed back to the smartphone app class associated with PendingIntent. I have tried

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(context, ProcessReplyActivity.class);
viewIntent.putExtra("test", "test");
PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, viewIntent, 0);
```

But when ProcessReplyActivity is created on the smartphone app - (after I choose a response on the wearable) - `getIntent().getStringExtra("test")` is **null**.

Is this the right way to go about it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last argument of your last line is wrong (presented in 2 lines for comfortable reading):

```
PendingIntent actionPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, viewIntent, 0);
```

You have probably already created such intent without the `test` extra and system is re-using the old one instead of using new one (with extras). You should use [`PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) to let system know that you want to use the newest possible version of this pending intent:

```
PendingIntent actionPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, viewIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

---

The same flag is used in official tutorial how to implement Voice Input in wearable notifications:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/voice-input.html#AddAction

```
// Create an intent for the reply action
Intent replyIntent = new Intent(this, ReplyActivity.class);
PendingIntent replyPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, replyIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: No problem:) To promote good quality answers you can also consider to upvote answers that are not only correct, but also helpful in any other way - like have additional explanation of the issue's reason etc.